# How to change symbol(character) of iconmoon font by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I can't find solution for this question, sorry if it is too stupid. 
For example I have button with search symbol(iconmoon font) and I need change search symbol on another by `hover`.

HTML: 
`<button class="share search-btn"><span class="icon-icn_search"></span></button>`

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:    url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:    url('fonts/icomoon.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?m23m4l') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?m23m4l') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?m23m4l#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.mls {
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 28px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-icn_search:before {
   content: "\e934";
}
.icon-icn_question_small_hover:before {
   content: "\e932";
}
.search-btn {
   background-color: #6670a7;
   padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}
.search-btn:hover{
   background-color: #434f93;
}
.search-btn:hover:before{
   content: "/e932";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: "/e932" instead of "\e932" is this a typo?

Comment: Yea, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should do the trick for you:

Remove this:

```
.search-btn:hover:before{
  content: "\e932";
}
```

Add this:

```
.search-btn:hover .icon-icn_search:before{
   content: "\e932";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me) Also my mistake was here 
"/e932" instead of "\e932" .

Answer (score 0):

```
.search-btn .icon-icn_search:before {
   content: "\e934";
}

.search-btn:hover .icon-icn_search:before {
   content: "...";
}
```